# Why java's Exchanger.Slot cache line padding like this?

Tags: java, disruptor-pattern

When I read the 'False sharing' mechnism in java, I find the following code in **java.util.concurrent.Exchanger.Slot**

```
    /**
 * A Slot is an AtomicReference with heuristic padding to lessen
 * cache effects of this heavily CAS'ed location.  While the
 * padding adds noticeable space, all slots are created only on
 * demand, and there will be more than one of them only when it
 * would improve throughput more than enough to outweigh using
 * extra space.
 */
private static final class Slot extends AtomicReference<Object> {
    // Improve likelihood of isolation on <= 64 byte cache lines
    long q0, q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8, q9, qa, qb, qc, qd, qe;
}
```

It's strange.Why the number of long is 15 (q0 - qe),
So I can calculate the size of the object should be:
15 * 8 (long) + 8 (parent's long value) + **16** (object header pointer at 64 bit jvm) = 144 byte.
or:
15 * 8 (long) + 8 (parent's long value) + **8** (object header pointer at 32 bit jvm) = 136 byte.
As I readed the [Disruptor's implemention:](http://mechanitis.blogspot.jp/2011/07/dissecting-disruptor-why-its-so-fast_22.html)

```
public long p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7; // cache line padding

private volatile long cursor = INITIAL_CURSOR_VALUE;

public long p8, p9, p10, p11, p12, p13, p14; // cache line padding
```

The size should be  7*8 + 8 + 7*8 + 8 (object head opinter'size at 32 bit jvm) = 128 = 64 * 2. 
As the default cache line size of most cpu is 64 byte, so the discruptor's impl can avoid the 'False sharing'.

So my question is the number of padded long at class 
**java.util.concurrent.Exchanger.Slot** is right or wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

The padding in `java.util.concurrent.Exchanger.Slot` is playing it safe. It is adding extra padding while on the other hand the disruptor is adding just enough.

Also the disruptor approach may fail if the JVM reorders the fields and the cache line size is 128 bits. The most safest approach is to separate fields through inheritance:

```
class MemoryFieldAddress {
    private long address;

    public final long getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    protected final void setAddress(final long address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}

class MemoryAddressPad1 extends MemoryFieldAddress {
    long p1_1, p1_2, p1_3, p1_4, p1_5, p1_6, p1_7, p1_8, p1_9, p1_10, p1_11, p1_12, p1_13, p1_14, p1_15, p1_16, p1_17;
}

class MemoryFieldBytes extends MemoryAddressPad1 {
    private long bytes;

    public final long getBytes() {
        return bytes;
    }

    protected final void setBytes(final long bytes) {
        this.bytes = bytes;
    }
}

class MemoryAddressPad2 extends MemoryFieldBytes {
    long p2_1, p2_2, p2_3, p2_4, p2_5, p2_6, p2_7, p2_8, p2_9, p2_10, p2_11, p2_12, p2_13, p2_14, p2_15, p2_16, p2_17;
}

// Finally the full implimentation
public class Memory extends MemoryAddressPad2 {}
```

If you want you can count final fields and rarely updated fields towards padding.

Answer (score 0):

for answering your question, you need to know the structure of java obj, by default ,java arranges the fields of obj in order like  long/double ,int ,oops ,.... for example：
what you see is as below:

```
public class testObj{
    int a,b,c;
    Object obj1;
    Object obj2;
    short s1,s2;
    long  l1,l2;
}
```

but actually, the arrangement is like below

```
    public class testObj{

    long l1,l2;
    int a,b,c;
    short s1,s2
    Object 1
    Object 2
}
```

which means the long fields q1.......qe will be arranged at the beginning of the java obj, which means at least it can fill the cache line before the field you want to protect, for the rest of the objects ,they can take at lest the rest of the cache line

1. cacheline 1  ----------++++++
2. cache line 2 ++++++++++ X(field you want to protect) ***
3. cache line 3 ******

---

(X） means the field you want to protect

---

（+） means the 120 bytes of the padding long field

---

（*） means the rest of the obj

for your case , it is an array , it is sequential, so it will be

> cacheline :  xxxxxxxx array[0]xx
>
> cacheline:   xxxxxxx array[1]xx

all these x are long slots padding